# Get the current month number in SQL Server, 1 for january, 12 for december

Tags: sql-server

How can I get current month in number in SQL Server?

Means for January I want 1 and for December I want 12.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())
```

This will return values 1 through 12 depending on the month.

[See the relevant MSDN documentation for details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) - that entire documentation site is **freely available** for consultation by everyone - **use it!**

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(datecolumn) from table
```

Also check for more details about **[MONTH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to get

```
SELECT MONTH('2015-10-16 00:00:00')
```

output

> 10

Comment: SQL Server does not have a `NOW()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You May Try Like This :

```
     DECLARE month INT;
     DECLARE transactionmonth INT;

    SELECT  NOW() into date;
    SELECT MONTH(date) into month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean & Simple,

```sql
SELECT MONTH(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL this can be achieved by:

`SELECT MONTH(NOW());`
OR
`SELECT MONTH(CURDATE())`

Also to compare current month with any DATE:

`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE MONTH(dateColumn) = MONTH(NOW());`

Answer (score 0):

In H2 Database:

```
SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) ;
```

Output:

**MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)  | YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)**
`2                       2020`